# Unsupported Configuration

Tags: ios5

I'm trying to understand the concept of the storyboard, but I get this warning:
`Unsupported Configuration: Segues initiated directly from view controllers must have an identifier for use with -[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]`

What I want to do:
I've got a tabbar with 4 tabs, these tabs lead to different NavigationControllers with TableViewControllers in them. The 4 different TableViewControllers share the same DetailViewController. When I try to connect the last connection (TableViewController -> NaviagtionViewController -> DetailViewController) I get that warning.

I hope I explained it clear enough.

Tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it, I forgot to specify an idintifier for the segue I created.

Answer (score 8):

When you get this warning and you have like 50 segues.. is there an easy way to find which is the one with identifier missing?

Comment: is there an answer for your question? since my project is huge.

Comment: The best advice I have is to expand the left sidebar in the IB view. I don't mean XCode's sidebar...but the nested sidebar when editing the storyboard. Then expand each view and click on each segue (with the right sidebar open) until you find one without an identifier.